# Need help in understanding the below .NET code

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql

This is a basically a class library project which is somehow exposed as a WCF service. The code below is a part of the Data Access Layer. 'db' is an object of a DataContext class. To save a file, we do the following-

```
public static Guid SaveFile(FileDetails fileDetails)
{
            System.Nullable<Guid> id = null;

            SystemDataContext.UsingWrite(db =>
                {
                    db.SaveFileData(fileDetails.RunId, fileDetails.FileData, fileDetails.FileExtension, ref id);
                });
            return id ?? Guid.Empty;
 }
```

Then, the below would execute-

```
 public static void UsingWrite(Action<SoftCashCreditDBDataContext> action)
 {
            using (var context = new SystemDataContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    action(context.Write);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    DataAccessExceptionHandler.HandleExcetion(ex, Config.DataLayerPolicy);
                }
            }
  }


 public SystemDataContext()
        {
            if (_stack == null)
            {
                _stack = new Stack<SystemDataContext>();
                this.Depth = 1;
                this.Read = new SoftCashCreditDBDataContext(Config.ReadDatabaseConnection);
                this.Write = new SoftCashCreditDBDataContext(Config.WriteDatabaseConnection);
            }
            else
            {
                var parent = _stack.Peek();
                /// Increment level of node.
                this.Depth = parent.Depth + 1;
                /// Copy data context from the parent
                this.Read = parent.Read;
                this.Write = parent.Write;
            }
            _stack.Push(this);
        }

        public int Depth { get; private set; }

        public bool IsRoot { get { return this.Depth == 1; } }

        [ThreadStatic]
        private static Stack<SystemDataContext> _stack = null;

        public SoftCashCreditDBDataContext Read { get; private set; }
        public SoftCashCreditDBDataContext Write { get; private set; }

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            var context = _stack.Pop();
            if (context.IsRoot == true)
            {
                context.Read.Dispose();
                context.Write.Dispose();
                _stack = null;
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

They have implemented LINQ to SQL here, and created a DBContext class. The 'SaveFileData()' method is actually part of that class, where it just calls an SP inside to save the file. 
**What I did not follow-
What exactly does the call to UsingWrite() do here? What is passed to the 'Action action' parameter, and what is it doing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your confusion. They use 2 delegates.

This is passed to the action parameter:

```
db =>
{
    db.SaveFileData(fileDetails.RunId, fileDetails.FileData, fileDetails.FileExtension, ref id);
}
```

So when UsingWrite is called, the SoftCashCreditDBDataContext delegate which was set in the Write delegate will call SaveFileData.

A simplified example to help you understand Action:

```
public void Main()
{
   Test(x => Debug.Write(x));
}

private void Test(Action<string> testAction)
{
   testAction("Bla");
}
```

This function will call Debug.Write with the argument x, which is a string that is passed to the test action function.